# Is top x% this week for a single community or all Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I've got "**top 2% this week**"  on the [Raspberry Pi community](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). I've read some posts about what does top x% this week means and I don't find the answer to this question.

In addition, on [Raspberry Pi User Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/447/week/raspberrypi), my account is the first one this week.

How this **2%** was calculated?

Comment: The formula is: `ceil(position/total_number_ranked)`. If you are #1 out of 99 people ranked then you are in the top 2%. Once the percentage goes below 1% more digits are shown; with more people listed in the league (108 ranked today) you are now the top 0.93%.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. This is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its related to/based on the reputation league and is based on your reputation per site.

What it shows kind of depends on both your "best" top score (so mine would show top per year on MSE and SU, even if I have a higher standing per week, for various reasons)